# How to display a files content in python

Tags: python

Here is my code so far. It prints out the encrypted text but won't print the text from the file before it is encrypted.

```
import string

char_set = string.printable[:-5]   
substitution_chars = char_set[-3:]+ char_set[:-3]    
encrypt_dict = {}

for i, k in enumerate (char_set):
    v = substitution_chars[i]
    encrypt_dict[k] = v

input_file=open('cryptopy_input.txt','r')    
text_list=list(input_file.read())

for i in range(len(text_list)):
    if text_list[i] in encrypt_dict:
        text_list[i]=encrypt_dict[text_list[i]]

output="".join(text_list)
output_file=open('cryptopy_output.txt','w')
output_file.write(output)
print(output)
output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line you are encrypting the text

```
text_list[i]=encrypt_dict[text_list[i]]
```

You are then appending that to output. And you are printing output. That is why what you are printing is already encrypted.

If you want to print the unencrypted text, print it before you encrypt it. Or store the encrypted text in a different variable.

Edit: I think your solution should look like this

```
for i in range(len(text_list)):
    print(text_list[i]
    if text_list[i] in encrypt_dict:
        text_list[i]=encrypt_dict[text_list[i]]
```

Comment: when I try to print before that line when I first open the file this is what I get                          <_io.TextIOWrapper name='cryptopy_input.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'> instead of the content that is in the .txt document

Comment: When you first open the file, text_list is like a pointer to the file. Each element in that list, text_list[i], is the actual line. So in the for loop, you need to print the lines.

Comment: So the data in the txt file is Hello my name is Jason and when I do                                text_list=list(input_file.read())
print(text_list) it give me this as an output.                  ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'J', 'a', 's', 'o', 'n', ' ']                                                                      how could I get it to show read 'hello my name is Jason' in one sting and not the list

Comment: Assuming that list you mentioned is stored in a variable named data, you can do something like this. str = "" and then on the next line str.join(data)